# Respository.save and saveAll operation are failing right after delete Operation in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have one service method in My SpringBoot Application. In that method I have List object as parameter and I will be checking if that object already contains in DB table, then I will delete it from DB and I will add it again with some more extra data. I am using @Transactional in repository method level.My insert operations  are [repository.save(entity) and repository.saveAll(entities)] failing with below given error

`Error during managed flush [Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)`

Repository Code

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "delete from  testTable where param1 = ?1 and param2 = ?2 ",nativeQuery = true)
    void testTable(String param1, String param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar problem just removing the @Transactional